# Socket.io several rooms in Construct2

Tags: socket.io, construct-2

I am working on a game in Construct2 at the moment.
It is a HTML5 Javascript Engine. 
I probably implement clay.io inside it.

My question however is about "Rooms"
Clay.io also helps with Rooms. However I am not sure If I will take that offer.
https://clay.io/docs/rooms

So when I want to limit the users per game to 10 for example. Would I then need to run two servers?

The socket.io server recives and returns data.. But would two games running with each 10 people not confuse the servers data?  When person A on server A shoots some1, that this information could somehow end up on Person B on server B?
Or do the assigned ID's prevent this somehow?

Here is the Example Server that I want to upgrade for my needs:

```
   var entities = [], count = 0;
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(8099);

    var INITIAL_X = 5;
    var INITIAL_Y = 5;
    var INITIAL_VEL_X = 0;
    var INITIAL_VEL_Y = 0;

    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
        var myNumber = count++;
        //assign number    
        var mySelf = entities[myNumber] = [myNumber, INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y, INITIAL_VEL_X, INITIAL_VEL_Y];

        //Send the initial position and ID to connecting player
    console.log(myNumber + ' sent: ' + 'I,' + mySelf[0] + ',' + mySelf[1] + ',' + mySelf[2]);
        socket.send('I,' + mySelf[0] + ',' + mySelf[1] + ',' + mySelf[2]);
        //Send to conencting client the current state of all the other players
        for (var entity_idx = 0; entity_idx < entities.length; entity_idx++) { 
//send initial update  
            if (entity_idx != myNumber) {
                entity = entities[entity_idx];
                if (typeof (entity) != "undefined" && entity != null) {

                console.log(myNumber + ' sent: C for ' + entity_idx);
                socket.send('C,' + entity[0] + ',' + entity[1] + ',' + entity[2]); 
//send the client that just connected the position of all the other clients 
            }
        }
    }
    //create new entity in all clients    
    socket.broadcast.emit("message",
        'C,' + mySelf[0] + ',' + mySelf[1] + ',' + mySelf[2]);
    socket.on("message", function (data) {

        //if (myNumber == 0)
        //    console.log(myNumber + ' sent: ' +data);
        var new_data = data.split(',');
        if (new_data[0] == 'UM') {
            mySelf[1] = new_data[1];
            mySelf[2] = new_data[2];
            mySelf[3] = new_data[3];
            mySelf[4] = new_data[4];
            //Update all the other clients about my update
            socket.broadcast.emit("message",
            'UM,' + mySelf[0] + ',' + mySelf[1] + ',' + mySelf[2] + ',' + mySelf[3] + ',' + mySelf[4]);
        }
        else if (new_data[0] == 'S') { // a s message
            var shoot_info = [];
            shoot_info[0] = new_data[1]; //ini x
            shoot_info[1] = new_data[2]; //ini y

            shoot_info[2] = new_data[3]; //degrees

            //Update all the other clients about my update
            socket.broadcast.emit("message",
            'S,' + mySelf[0] + ',' + shoot_info[0] + ',' + shoot_info[1] + ',' + shoot_info[2]);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io has rooms that you can limit the broadcasts to, see: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Then rather than use `socket.broadcast.emit` you would use `io.sockets.in('roomname').emit`

A good way to mesh this with Clay.io is to have the room name be the room.id (in the Construct 2 plugin that's the RoomId expression). When the Clay.io room fills up (in C2 there's a condition for that), create the Socket.io room using that unique ID and put the players who "Rooms Filled" was just called for in that room.

I know it's a bit different since it's a game written in CoffeeScript instead of Construct 2, but we're using Clay.io rooms + Socket.io rooms in our Slime Volley game. [Here is the code.](https://github.com/claydotio/Slime-Volley/tree/master/src)